# Adding windows command line prompt right click option to Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven-2, eclipse-plugin, helios

I was wondering if anyone knew of a plugin or some other capability that would allow me to right click on a project in Eclipse and have an option for a Windows command line prompt to appear from the directory (or file) that I clicked on. When I want to do some Maven command line work with my projects I find this would be incredibly helpful.

Comment: Do you need to do things that m2eclipse doesn't handle?

Comment: On enough occasions to notice, yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe [StartExplorer](http://startexplorer.sourceforge.net/) is what you are looking for.

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I wanted. Thank you. Will accept when the timer lets me.

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be [Tarlog-plugins](http://code.google.com/p/tarlog-plugins/). It is a lightweight eclipse plugin that adds three contextual menus to projects and files:

- Open Explorer
- Open Shell
- Copy path

Answer (score 1):

Newer versions of Eclipse (since ~2014) that get installed with the [*Oomph* Installer](https://www.eclipse.org/community/eclipse_newsletter/2014/may/article3.php)  offer the option to install a small feature called "Oomph OS Tools". The package's tagline is *"Contains a popup actions that start the OS-specific system explorer or command prompt on the selected workspace resource."*

It then adds two menu items that look like this:

[image]

The tools can be added later with the "install New Software..." Menu